# how to parse nested json object

Tags: c, json, parsing

I am using json parser lib written in C to parse JSON objects. The lib link is :  https://github.com/udp/json-parser.

The json object/string, which I am trying to parse is :

{"video_id": 105, "st": "S3", "processing" : [{"start" : "1", "end" : "2"}]}}

"processing" contains another JSON object.

I have parsed the first three items. But I am not able to figure out a way to parse the **"processing"** json object. I am using following code:-

```
   if (!strcmp(json->u.object.values[i].name, "video_id")) 
    {
      video_id=json->u.object.values[i].value->u.integer;
    }
    .
    .
    if (!strcmp(json->u.object.values[i].name, "processing")) 
    {
         printf("\nNumber of JSON OBJECTS : %d\n", json->u.object.values[i].value->u.object.length); 
    }
```

json is the parsed object obtained via calling the lib on the JSON string. Can anyone guide me how to handle the nested object ?

Any help will be really appreciated

My complete code is :

```
json_value *json;                                                   
json_char *json_object="{\"video_id\": 105, \"st\": \"S3\", \"processing\" : [{\"type\" : \"clipping\"},{\"fese\" : \"dipping\"}]}";



    printf("%s",json_object);
    //json_value * json_parse (const json_char * json,
      //                   size_t length);
    json=json_parse(json_object, strlen(json_object));

//  json_type json_object;


    printf("\n%s\n",json->u.object.values[0].name);
    printf("\t%d\n",json->u.object.values[0].value->u.integer);

    printf("\n%s\n",json->u.object.values[2].name);
    printf("\t%d\n",json->u.object.values[2].value->u.object.length);

printf("\t%s\n",json->u.object.values[2].value->u.object.values[0].name);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/udp/json-parser), API field::

The `type` field of `json_value` is one of:

- json_object (see u.object.length, u.object.values[x].name, u.object.values[x].value)
- **json_array** (see u.array.length, u.array.values)
- json_integer (see u.integer)
- json_double (see u.dbl)
- json_string (see u.string.ptr, u.string.length)
- json_boolean (see u.boolean)
- json_null

So, check the `type` field of the "processing" value. If found to be `json_array`, do a `json_parse` for the array to get a new `json_value`. Now this `json_value` will provide you with the nested JSON objects.

Comment: HI. .  u mean that I should check IF (json->u.object.values[i].type==JSON_OBJECT), then parse that again by using json_parse function. Plz correct me if I am wrong . . .

Comment: Can you post the structure for `json_value`? I think you have to check `if( json->u.object.values[i].type == json_array )` and then again parse using `json_parse`.

Comment: hi, I have provided code in my question, which I am using just to read values of nested structure. But no luck so far. . Plz have a look and let me know. So I can experiment with the new stuff. It tell me exactly that there are two nested JSON objects but I cannot figure out a way to read them .

Answer (score 0):

Take these as reference:

```
js_v->u.object.values[1].value->u.array.values[0]->type
js_v->u.object.values[1].value->u.array.values[0]->u.string.ptr
```

I've used them to reference to a string element inside an array:
`{"t":"type","d":["element1","element2","element3"]}`

In your case, I think you should to repeat the structure like this:
`js_v->u.object.values[2].value->u.array.values[0]->u.object.values[0]->u.string.ptr`

luck!